# Generate consecutive and same number on Array effectively in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have an example of a case in the application to create a numeric pin pattern that should not have a consecutive number and the same number of all.

Examples of PIN patterns that are rejected are as follows:

123456,
234567,
345678,
654321,
765432,
876543,
000000 and other similar PIN patterns.

```
var rejectedPinList: [[Int]] = [[Int]]()
var consecutiveNumber = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

func incrementNumber(currentIndex: Int) -> [Int] {
    var rejectedPinPattern: [Int] = [Int]()
    for currentIndex in stride(from: currentIndex, to: currentIndex+6, by: 1){
        rejectedPinPattern.append(consecutiveNumber[currentIndex])
    }
    return rejectedPinPattern
}

func decrementNumber(currentIndex: Int) -> [Int] {
    var rejectedPinPattern: [Int] = [Int]()
    for currentIndex in stride(from: currentIndex, to: currentIndex-6, by: -1){
        rejectedPinPattern.append(consecutiveNumber[currentIndex])
    }
    return rejectedPinPattern
}

func constantNumber(currentIndex: Int) -> [Int] {
    var rejectedPinPattern: [Int] = [Int]()
    for _ in currentIndex...currentIndex+6  {
        rejectedPinPattern.append(consecutiveNumber[currentIndex])
    }
    return rejectedPinPattern
}


for number in consecutiveNumber {
    rejectedPinList.append(constantNumber(currentIndex: number))
    if number < 5 {
        rejectedPinList.append(incrementNumber(currentIndex: number))
    } else if number > 5 {
        rejectedPinList.append(decrementNumber(currentIndex: number))
    } else {
        rejectedPinList.append(incrementNumber(currentIndex: number))
        rejectedPinList.append(decrementNumber(currentIndex: number))
    }
}

func inputPin(pin: [Int]) {
    if rejectedPinList.contains(pin) {
        print("Pin Rejected!")
    } else {
    }
}
inputPin(pin: [8,7,6,5,4,3]) // Should be Rejected!
```

What I'm looking for is to be more effective than the algorithm code I made above in generating consecutive & same numbers. Because in my opinion, the code I made is too long and not very effective and may be wasteful. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you not using random numbers ```Int.random(in: 0..<9)``` to generate a PIN?  It will have less probability of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Are any consecutive digits allowed or none at all?  E.g. is 561924 valid? Are any duplicated digits allowed? E.g. is 419314 valid?

Comment: I assume it would be easier to check a given pin for increasing/decreasing/identical characters than creating a list of all “blocked” pins in advance.

Comment: Hi @Afsaredrisy , I just changed the name of the variable to avoid misunderstanding. You can check again.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 , 561924 is valid and 419314 is also valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you want.  It checks to see if there are any consecutive digits that have an absolute difference that isn't 1.  If so then the PIN may be valid (pending a check for repeated digits).

To check for repeated digits, the digits are added to an `NSCountedSet`.  If the count for any digit is the same as the number of digits then the PIN is invalid.

```
func validatePIN(_ candidate: [Int]) -> Bool {
    
    guard !candidate.isEmpty else {
        return false
    }
    
    let digitSet = NSCountedSet()
    
    var possiblyValid = false
    var lastSign: Int?
    
    for i in 0..<candidate.count {
        digitSet.add(candidate[i])
        if i > 0 && !possiblyValid {
            let difference = candidate[i]-candidate[i-1]
            let thisSign = difference.signum()
            if abs(difference) != 1 {
                possiblyValid = true
            } else if let sign = lastSign, sign != thisSign {
                possiblyValid = true
            }
            lastSign = thisSign
        }
    }
    
    for digit in digitSet {
        if digitSet.count(for: digit) == candidate.count {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return possiblyValid
}

print(validatePIN([]))
print(validatePIN([8,7,6,5,3,3]))
print(validatePIN([8,7,6,5,4,3]))
print(validatePIN([2,2,2,2,2,2]))
print(validatePIN([1,2,3,4,3,2]))
```

gives:

> false
>
> true
>
> false
>
> false
>
> true

You could also add a test for minimum length in the `guard` statement

Comment: Note that this would reject [1,2,3,4,3,2].

Comment: Good catch.  Fixed that.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of computing a list of all invalid pins in advance, you can verify the given pin by computing the set of all differences of adjacent digits. A pin is invalid if the set consists of `-1`, `0`, or `+1` only:

```
func validatePIN(_ pin: [Int]) -> Bool {

    if pin.isEmpty { return false }

    let diffs = Set(zip(pin, pin.dropFirst()).map(-))
    return diffs.count != 1 || abs(diffs.first!) > 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the question was to improve efficiency, the approach below this implements the some initial checks before it starts looping through the array to minimise the total number of iterations/time.

```
func validatePin(_ pin: [Int], minLength: Int = 2 ) -> Bool {
   guard pin.count >= max(minLength, 2)  else {return false}

   guard Set(pin).count != 1 else {return false}  //all the same

   guard abs(pin.first! - pin.last!) == pin.count - 1 else {return true} //can't be a sequence

   let delta = pin.first! < pin.last! ? -1 : 1
   for index in (0...pin.count - 2) {
      if pin[index] - pin[index + 1] != delta {return true}  //items not sequential
   }
   return false  //items are sequential
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping me. I also improvise my algorithm. Here's my code:

```
func validatePIN(_ pin: [Int]) -> Bool {
    if (pin.isEmpty == true) ||
        (pin[0] < 5 && pin == Array(pin[0]...pin[0]+5)) ||
        (pin[0] > 5 && pin == Array(stride(from: pin[0], through: pin[0]-5, by: -1)) ||
        (pin.allSatisfy({ $0 == pin[0] }))) { return false }; return true
}
```

Comment: Note that this would reject [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1]. You check only if the first and the last digit are equal, not if *all* digits are equal.

Comment: Also your code *crashes* for the pin [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]. You might want to replace `pin[0] < 5` by `pin[0] < pin[5]` .

Comment: The last check can be simplified to `pin.allSatisfy({ $0 == pin[0] })`

Comment: Great! Thank you.